# Why is a Nonetype being returned?

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype, operand

I'm fairly new to Python. I am making a generator that gives a bakery estimates on how much it would take to host an event if they were making cupcakes. Something goes wrong around here though

```
Batches = print("Batches of Cupcakes:", math.ceil(People * Ingredients / 12))

Labor = print("Hours of labor:", Batches * 1.25)
```

I receive this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Comment: `print` doesn't return anything, so `Batches` is `NoneType`

Comment: Pedantic: Technically, `Batches` is `None`, which is the only instance of type `NoneType`, `Batches` isn't the type itself.

Comment: try: `type(Batches)`

Comment: "Something goes wrong" - did you try anything to troubleshoot it? You are supposed to make attempts to solve your own issue before asking a question, rather than giving up as soon as you see an error message.

Answer (score 3):

Because `print` always returns None. You want to save the previous result in a variable:

```
batches = math.ceil(people * ingredients/12)
labor = batches * 1.25

print("Batches of cupcakes:", batches)
print("Hours of labor:", labor)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was definitely a case of coding too fast.

Answer (score 0):

`print()` returns nothing, so you're trying to do multiplication with nothing, which is where the "NoneType" error comes in.

If you want `Batches` to be a number,

```
Batches = math.ceil(People * Ingredients / 12)
```

Print simply outputs text to a python interpreter :)

Your entire code should look like this:

```
Batches = math.ceil(People * Ingredients / 12)
Labor = Batches * 1.25
```

and then you can display the data like this:

```
print("Batches of cupcakes:", Batches)
print("Hours of labor:", Labor)
```

Comment: string + int makes type error. And I don't know what you are talking about regarding an extra newline character, the print function inserts a space by default.

Comment: @L3viathan I apologize, I have corrected my mistakes. I always forget about the string and non-string concatenation in Python